# Made some components in render() as viewport size responsive and I get hydration failed error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, hydration

My `header.tsx` had such code.

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import { HeaderMenu } from './menu/headerMenu';
import { HamburgerButtons, HamburgerMenu } from './menu/hamburgerMenu';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SearchForm from './searchForm';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import SmartLink from './links';

const Header = ({ isFixed }: { isFixed?: boolean }) => {
  const [isHamburgerOpen, toggleHamburger] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const toggleHamburgerMenu = (): void => {
    isHamburgerOpen ? toggleHamburger(false) : toggleHamburger(true);
  }

  return (
    <header className={classNames(isFixed && 'fixed')}>
      <SmartLink href="/">
        <Image src="/logos/eeat-low-resolution-logo-color-on-transparent-background.svg" alt="Logo" width="70" height="85"/>
      </SmartLink>

      <HeaderMenu/>

      <div className="flex flexItemsCenter">
        <SearchForm placeholder="SEARCH..."/>
        <HamburgerButtons onClick={toggleHamburgerMenu} isHamburgerOpen={isHamburgerOpen}/>
      </div>

      <HamburgerMenu isHamburgerOpen={isHamburgerOpen}/>
  </header>
  )
};
export default Header;
```

but later I got an idea to do not render these `<HamburgerMenu>` and `<HamburgerButtons>` components when viewport size is desktop mode.

So I installed npm package `react-responsive` and added this logic in `Header` component.

```
const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 992px)' });
```

and used this `isDesktop` to decide to render these components or not. So this is the final code of the `Header`.

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';
import { HeaderMenu } from './menu/headerMenu';
import { HamburgerButtons, HamburgerMenu } from './menu/hamburgerMenu';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SearchForm from './searchForm';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import SmartLink from './links';

const Header = ({ isFixed }: { isFixed?: boolean }) => {
  const [isHamburgerOpen, toggleHamburger] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const toggleHamburgerMenu = (): void => {
    isHamburgerOpen ? toggleHamburger(false) : toggleHamburger(true);
  }

  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 992px)' });

  return (
    <header className={classNames(isFixed && 'fixed')}>
        <SmartLink href="/">
          <Image src="/logos/eeat-low-resolution-logo-color-on-transparent-background.svg" alt="Logo" width="70" height="85"/>
        </SmartLink>

        <HeaderMenu/>

        <div className="flex flexItemsCenter">
          <SearchForm placeholder="SEARCH..."/>
          {!isDesktop && <HamburgerButtons onClick={toggleHamburgerMenu} isHamburgerOpen={isHamburgerOpen}/>}
        </div>

        {!isDesktop && <HamburgerMenu isHamburgerOpen={isHamburgerOpen}/>}
    </header>
  )
};
export default Header;
```

Now, I get

> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

if I reload the page in Desktop viewport size.

[image]

but page works if I start page as mobile viewport size.

How do I solve this issue?

`HamburgerMenu`  and `HamburgerButtons` look like this:

```
import classnames from 'classnames'
import { HeaderMenu } from './headerMenu'

export const HamburgerButtons = ({ onClick, isHamburgerOpen }: { onClick: () => void, isHamburgerOpen: boolean }) => (
    <div id="HamburgerButtons" className={classnames(isHamburgerOpen && 'hamburgerOpen')} onClick={onClick}>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
)

 export const HamburgerMenu = ({ isHamburgerOpen }: { isHamburgerOpen: boolean }) => {
   return (
        <div id="Hamburger" className={classnames(isHamburgerOpen && 'hamburgerMenuOpen')}>
            <HeaderMenu id="HamburgerHeaderMenu"/>
        </div>
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `react-responsive` package is not suitable for SSR applications. After some investigations, I found some people mentioned already `react-responsive` having trouble with SSR applications.

The last answer https://github.com/yocontra/react-responsive/issues/312 here helped me a lot.

```
  const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(false);

  const isDesktopView = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 992px)' });

  useEffect(() => { setIsDesktop(isDesktopView) }, [isDesktopView]);
```

This code solved my issue.